# Sublimetext3 on_query_completion show blank row

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I just trying to make sublime plugin for java auto completion.
which when I typing dot after some variables it will looking for any field or method of that variables.

it's works nicely when i using `quick_panel`. but it's look to bigger and its position can not be moved.

when I using `on_query_completions` to populate auto complete list programmatically it's just showing blank row like this:

[image: link to image]

and here is the code:

```
class yooCommand(sublime_plugin.ViewEventListener ):
    def on_query_completions(self, prefix, locations):
        return (
            [
                ["me1","run()"],
                ["me2","some()"]
            ],
        sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS |  sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS
        )
```

I guess maybe this is because of a package I installed.
is there anyone who has experience like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem.

This is because Sublime plugin called `hacklang typehacker and autocompletion`.
And now sublime became more fun place:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxlFz.png)